Javascript .click() function is not working
I am trying out Javascript on Microsofts platform from the console.
What I have done, is to enter the value of the form like this
document.forms[0][0].value="test@test.com";

When I search for the next button, I can do that file as well
document.forms[0][3]

https://imgur.com/a/JUn9tKt
My problem occur when I try to click the button with javascript using
document.forms[0][3].click()

https://imgur.com/a/b3cit0E
What is strange here is that when i MANUALLY click the button "Next" it works, but it doesnt seem to work with JavaScript.
What am i doing wrong?

Those index numbers mean nothing without the HTML. Do yourself a favor, call functions like document.getElementById() or document.querySelector() to access DOM elements.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

The links in OP look suspicious.

I used document.getElementById("i0116").value = "test@test.com"; and
document.getElementById("idSIButton9").click()
This still gives the same issue

A comment with just two statements and no HTML is not a [mre].

You need to post enough code so we can see what clicking the button is supposed to do, and figure out why it isn't doing it.

And post it as text (preferably a Stack Snippet), not a screenshot.

@Barmar All the code necessary to reproduce the problem is provided in the question. Try visiting login.microsoftonline.com and enter the commands document.forms[0][0].value="test@test.com"; and document.forms[0][3].click(). You will see exactly what is shown in both screenshots. I see no problem with the question. The problem is explained very short and clear.

@Foxyz That information should be in the question itself. Comments are always subject to deletion. And it was hardly obvious that you were talking about a third-party site, not code you wrote.

I tried it and I noticed under what conditions this occurs. It only gives an error if you enter the value programatically and then click submit.
The problem isn't that the submit click isn't working, the problem is with entering the email address in the input field. The email is being typed in the field but the underlying javascript is probably not triggered from setting the value through script. Manually clicking the text field and then running the click function works.
I noticed the JavaScript that sets the email address entered in the input field is triggered once you click outside the input field. This leads me to believe it's an event listener that sets a variable in JavaScript, and this variable is what's being sent to the server and not the input from the field directly.
To work around this we will first do a bit of reverse engineering to see how it works. Luckily JavaScript is very simple and we can easily see all event listeners using the handy developer tools in our browser like Firefox:

and Chrome:

All we need to do is try to send some of these events and see which ones are effective.
To determine if the event I was sending worked I first sent the click event to the next button to make it show the error, basically doing exactly what you did to purposefully make it fail, and tried sending events to the input field until the error disappeared since manually clicking next to the input field made the error disappear too, indicating that it refreshed the JavaScript value for the input field through an event listener.
Since we know the JavaScript is triggered when something happens to the input field, we can begin with assuming the input field has an event listener that
I first tried sending focus and blur events. These didn't work, so I tried select which also didn't work. Then I tried the change event and success!
Here is the JavaScript code I wrote for this:
{
  const event = new Event("change");
  document.forms[0][0].value="test@test.com";
  document.forms[0][0].dispatchEvent(event);
  document.forms[0][3].click();
}

Note that I placed it in a block, that's just to adjust the scope to avoid redeclaring that event variable since one might potentially want to paste this script in the console multiple times.
In simple words, here is what we do:

Create a new Event object (using the Event constructor, since createEvent is deprecated).
Initialize our event as type "change"
Set the value the way you initally tried.
Dispatch our "change" event on the input field to trigger the JavaScript to take the value of the input field and store it in its variable.
Click the next button.

Another improvement to make is to avoid repeating ourselves like this:
{
  const email = "test@test.com"; // We separate this to make modifying easier.

  const form = document.forms[0];
  form[0].value = email;
  form[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  form[3].click();
}

If you have any other problems or questions regarding your journey of learning JavaScript, you're more than welcome to ask for help! If any of my steps are unclear you can let me know, I try to explain the thought process a bit so you can learn how to use the available tools to troubleshoot the problems you encounter so you not only get a solution but also have an understanding of where that solution came from.

Event.initEvent() is deprecated. You can use const event = new Event("change") instead.

Hi @Foxyz could you please edit your picture because I cannot see it in your reply?

Foxyz, could you also tell me why I cannot use a random click for example  document.getElementById("i0281").click(); (Click outside box) it doesnt work? Im really curious how you found the solution from needing an event, but I cannot see that in the picture

@PRO Thank you for letting me know! I haven't used event handlers for a while so it's a bit of learning what parts of it are deprecated. Doing it the way you explain makes way more sense, I was wondering what the parameter was required for. I will update the code.

@phil_sw I tried manually clicking next to the box and that also didn't work. It only let me click the next button once I first clicked on the input field and then clicked somewhere else. I actually thought of simulating click events using events instead of the click() function first. I wasn't sure if it was only reading the input field after a click event was made inside a certain area of the screen or if it might be listening to the click events on the parent elements of the input field. The way for JavaScript to be triggered is event listeners, so I tried simulating events on input field.
